# Como consertar múltiplos erros no neste código?

Tags: c, c++

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo um código que precisa conter 3 vetores (núm. de matrícula, nota 1 e nota 2), relativo a 6 alunos, no qual precisa constar:

- a nota final de cada aluno;
- a média da turma;
- o núm. de alunos com nota abaixo da média da turma.

Fiz o código pelo que sei, porém ele não compilou, (algum erro na declaração da variável `vetor`). E imprimir estilo tabela como se faz?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{
float nota1 [6], nota2 [6], nf, medturma;
  int nm [6];
int i;

for (i=0;i<=6; i++);
{
         printf("Informe o número de matrícula %d :", i);
         scanf("%d", &nm[i]);

      printf("Informe a nota 1 do aluno %d:", i);
      scanf("%f", &nota1[i]);

     printf("Informe a nota 2 do aluno %d:", i);
    scanf("%f", &nota2[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<=6; i++)
{
    nf= (nota1[i] + nota2[i])/2;
}
    printf("A nota final de cada aluno é :",i);

    medturma=nf[i]/6;
    printf("A media da turma foi %f:", i);


    if (nf<medturma)
        printf("Notas abaixo da média %f:", i);


    }
```

Comment: o erro esta ocorrendo porque na linha 28 você esta passando a variavel `nf` como se fosse um vetor, no caso você deveria declara-la acima como `nf[6]` para que pudesse dar certo, essa foi apenas a analise de compilação, corrigindo isto ele irá compilar

Comment: Ainda persiste o erro.

Comment: É duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86842/como-usar-vetores

Comment: Pode me ajudar? Aquela hora mandei via cel. a imagem (não tinha como mandar)

Comment: @bigown a url parece a mesma..

Comment: Explique o que o programa deve fazer. Ele nem compila, tem uma quantidade enorme de erros. Principalmente a segunda parte está bem confusa.

Comment: programa para ler e armazenar (em três vetores) o Número de Matricula 
(inteiro), a Nota1 (real) e a Nota2 (real) de cada aluno de uma turma de 6 alunos. 
Calcular a nota final de cada aluno, a média da turma, o número de alunos com nota final 
inferior à média. Imprimir no final todos os dados envolvidos estilo tabela

Comment: @user32720 eu percebi que você só deu um voto até hoje. Você sabia que pode votar em tudo no site? Qualquer coisa que te ajudou nas perguntas que fez, ou mesmo em outras perguntas. E pode aceitar uma resposta como a mais correta em todas perguntas que você já fez. Você não é obrigado fazer isto, mas é interessante para todos que faça. Classifica e indica melhor o que foi útil para você. Claro que não deve votar em coisas que não considere úteis ou que não ajudou. Veja o [tour] para entender melhor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta está inconsistente mas fiz o que dava:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    float nota1[6], nota2[6], nf = 0;
    int nm[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("\nInforme o número de matrícula %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &nm[i]);
        printf("\nInforme a nota 1 do aluno %d:", i);
        scanf("%f", &nota1[i]);
        printf("\nInforme a nota 2 do aluno %d:", i);
        scanf("%f", &nota2[i]);
    }
    printf("\nMatricula Nota1 Nota2 Nota final\n");
    float notaTotalALunos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        nf = (nota1[i] + nota2[i]) / 2;
        notaTotalALunos += nf;
        printf("%d         %2.2f  %2.2f  %2.2f\n", nm[i], nota1[i], nota2[i], nf);
    }
    float medturma = notaTotalALunos / 6;
    printf("A media da turma foi: %2.2f\n", medturma);
    int alunosAbaixoDaMedia = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) if ((nota1[i] + nota2[i]) / 2 < medturma) alunosAbaixoDaMedia++;
    printf("Notas abaixo da média %d:", alunosAbaixoDaMedia);
 }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ZcCXyf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ecgohlqk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Grades2.c).

Tinha uma quantidade enorme de erros que eu não saberia nem por onde começar. Eu tenho quase certeza que ainda não faz o que é desejado mas está mais próximo. Fora que isto pode ser uma forma de fazer para um exercício mas jamais se faria desta forma em um programa real.

O estilo estava ruim e eu melhorei mas poderia ter melhorado mais, não quis descaracterizar demais o código já escrito.

Se tiver dúvidas específicas de como funciona cada coisa, vai abrindo perguntas específicas.

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda! Tanto o gabriel quanto o bigown! Porém, o primeiro programa tem variáveis que ainda não estudei!

Answer (score 2):

Solução implementada em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

float n1[6],n2[6],mediaTurma = 0;
int nrMatricula[6], maxCad = 2, mediaInferior = 0 ;

for(int i = 0 ;i < maxCad;i++){
    cout << "Informe o numero de Matricula "<< i+1 << " : ";
    cin >> nrMatricula[i];
    cout << "Informe a nota da  N1: ";
    cin >> n1[i];
    cout << "Informe a nota da  N2: ";
    cin >> n2[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < maxCad;i++){
    float mediaAluno = (n1[i] + n2[i])/2;
    cout << "No. Matricula: " << nrMatricula[i] << endl;
    cout << "Nota 01: " << n1[i] << endl;
    cout << "Nota 02: " << n2[i] << endl;
    cout << "Nota Final: " << mediaAluno << endl;
    mediaTurma += mediaAluno;
    if(mediaAluno < 7){
       mediaInferior++;
    }
 }
 cout << "A media da turma e: " << mediaTurma/maxCad << endl;
 cout << "Número de Alunos com nota final inferior a media: " <<  mediaInferior << endl;
 return 0;
}
```